# Actionbar not changing custom style android

Tags: android, xml

**Manifest:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".SalesforceMainPage"
    android:label="@string/sfhomepage"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.tmobile3.SalesforceMainPage" /> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.tmobile3.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

**themes.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_sfhomepage</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I want to use my custom style color yellow action bar but its not working

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: DO you want to show color on actionbar or different image ??

Comment: Yes  i want to change the color of the actionbar